# Block until a task finished in onAnimationEnd

Tags: android, multithreading, animation

I have a login activity which has an animation displaying the logo picture, and the login process is running in the background during the animation running. I want to wait until both the animation and the login process finished to execute the next part of the program.
My first attempt is put the login process in a thread, and in `onAnimationEnd` use `thread.join()` to block until the thread finished.
It seems to be a good solution, however since I use `thread.join()`, the main UI thread was blocked, hence ANR may occure. I've tried to use `AsyncTask`, however it cannot handle `onAnimationEnd` event. Is there any other way to solute the problem?

The code is like this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ........
    title.startAnimation(set);
    loginProcess.start();
    ........
}

public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
    try {
        loginProcess.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ........
}
```

Comment: why dont you just complete the loading animation when the login process is done

Comment: @FrancisFuerte I don't want to interrupt the animation, need it to be displayed completely

Comment: why is there a need to join the threads again?

Comment: To block until the thread finished

Answer (score 1):

Just use an **AsyncTask** and do something like:

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
        title.startAnimation(set);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
       title.clearAnimation();
}
```

Comment: It's a good suggestion, however the animation will be force finished. I need the animation being complete.